# Вставка ресурсов в jar

Tags: jar, java, swing

Добрый день. Я сейчас делаю проект на java se desktop приложение. У меня есть картинки которые я использую для оформления интерфейса. Разрабатываю я в среде netbeans. Как мне прописать и что чтобы картинки засунуть в jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке проекта находишь папку src, создаёшь в ней папку resources (или с любым другим именем) и кидаешь картинки в неё. Выполняешь Clean and Build, и в jar-ку добавляются твои ресурсы. Чтобы получить к ним доступ, используй следующий код:

```
String path = "resources/yourImage.png";
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Здесь MyClass - любой класс из твоего проекта. Подробнее про `getResourceAsStream` можно прочитать в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) к классу Class.

Comment: а это можно сделать средствами netbeans? или только ручками?

Comment: Средствами Netbeans можно разве что создать папку (правой кнопкой по папке Source Packages -> New -> Java Package), файлы придётся копировать вручную.

Comment: Делается средствами Netbeans: указывается в таргетах jar'а что пихать в ресурсы

Comment: а вот тут можно по подробнее, можно даже ссылочками что именно почитать

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку решения. После часа проб и ошибок все заработало, и теперь действительно картинки лежат в jar и подгружаются. Единственное уточнение, у меня работает вот так:

String path = "/resources/yourImage.png";

то есть нужно было добавить еще один слешь в начале адреса.