# Получение пути к изображению из JAR файла

Tags: java

У меня есть код, который спокойно запускается в IDEA. Но когда создаешь из него JAR файл, он не запускается.

**java -jar jarname.jar**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:15)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Что у меня находится в MainClass (15 строка):**

```
frame.setIconImage(newImageIcon(MainClass.class.getResource("gui\\img\\reg.png")).getImage());
```

Comment: Вместо `"gui\\img\\reg.png"` попробуй использовать глобальный путь к файлу `red.png`.

Comment: Дело в том что файл reg.png должен хранится в jar файле, и если я укажу абсолютный путь то jar файл будет открыватся только у меня на компютере. А мне надо чтобы запускалось везде. Извините если я не так вас понял

Comment: Поможет? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1096491/6104996  ..... вот на русском другой вариант http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/185542/191482